# Manipulate the files uploaded via Gravity Forms before they are stored

Tags: uploads, plugin-gravity-forms

I would like to make changes to files (for e.g. compress them into a zip) **uploaded via Gravity Forms File upload field *before*** they are uploaded to the webserver.

Do you know of any hook or workaround to modify the (temporary) file **before** it is sent to and stored on the webserver?

(I have found a solution to do it **after** the files are uploaded, but that is not what I am looking for.)

Comment: not sure but maybe you could try using `gravity_forms_upload_filename` filter to trigger the zipping and change the filename

Comment: @majick according to docs.gravityforms.com search "No results were found for "gravity_forms_upload_filename"." Tried with "gravity_form_upload_filename" as well. Can you please provide a link ?

Comment: sorry my bad, I didn't check that properly. I took that from a project customization file - it looked like a standard filter...well since I put my foot in it, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was using this class to do this:
http://gravitywiz.com/rename-uploaded-files-for-gravity-form/ 
and added the filter in myself after line 207, ie.

```
    // replace merge tags
    $form  = GFAPI::get_form( $entry['form_id'] );
    $value = GFCommon::replace_variables( $value, $form, $entry, false, true, false, 'text' );

    // MOD: add a filter here to hook into filename change
    $value = apply_filters('gravity_forms_upload_filename', $value, $entry);
```

`$value` will then contain the full path to then uploaded file which can be hooked into and zipped so you can return the zip path instead.

Here is the snippet I was using to load `GW_Rename_Uploaded_Files`:

```
add_action('init', 'my_forms_rename_uploads', 11);
if (!function_exists('my_forms_rename_uploads')) {
 function my_forms_rename_uploads() {
    if (!class_exists('GW_Rename_Uploaded_Files')) {return;}
    $form_ids = array(
        1, // list of form IDs to load renaming class for
    );

    // --- get all file upload fields ---
    foreach ($form_ids as $form_id) {
        $upload_field_ids = array();
        $form = GFFormsModel::get_form_meta($form_id);
        if (isset($form['fields'])) {
            // --- get upload field IDs ---
            foreach ($form['fields'] as $field) {
                if ($field->type == 'fileupload') {$upload_field_ids[] = $field->id;}
            }
            // --- set class arguments ---
            $args = array(
                'form_id' => $form_id,
                'field_id' => $upload_field_ids,
                'template' => '{filename}'
            );
            // --- initialize rename uploaded files class for fields ---
            new GW_Rename_Uploaded_Files($args);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: "$value will then contain the full path to then uploaded file" – so the file is (will be) already on the server when you start processing (rename, compress, etc.) ?

Comment: I believe so, I think they are written when the form is processed and this hooks in after that, but not 100% sure without trawling through Gravity Forms code.

Comment: if the filename filter doesn't work where it is (ie. if the value is not actually the file's file path), then you can move that filter into the `increment_file` function of the class, the full filename path is definitely available there via `$file_path = GFFormsModel::get_physical_file_path( $file );`